# about the red5 room

Tags: red5

I have a problem about the red5 room,when I enter a room it will trigger the appDisconnect event.as that,when I close the browser,it just trigger the roomDisconnect, so I can't get the time that when the user exit the system,I just can't get when him left the room. does somebody
have this issue?and how to do it ? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

roomDisconnect does not exist :) I guess you mean

```
@Override
public void roomLeave(IClient client, IScope room) { ... }
```

the Event roomLeave will give you basically the same information compared to appDisconnect.
In fact a user can't leave the room without disconnecting.
And disconnecting cannot happen without leaving the room.

It is just a matter of the time when the events are thrown.
roomLeave is called *before* appDisconnect.

However we had the same issues with appDiconnect not being called sometimes. 
The is why I changed everyting to use roomLeave.
And meanwhile I think roomLeave also makes more sense as at the moment when roomLeave is called you can still access the users IConnection and read some values from it.
While at "appDisconnect" I think the IConnection of the user is already gone.

Sebastian

Comment: thank you for you answer, yes ,While at "appDisconnect" I think the IConnection of the user is already gone. so I can't get the user info ,and then it will appear many wrong.I don't know why the appDisconnect while I enter a room

Comment: so why not simply use roomLeave event and forget about appDisconnect ?